# Loop a userform

Tags: vba, loops, userform

I made a user form which transfer data from the text boxes and combo boxes to a spreadsheet.

I would like to run this form multiple times and for each time to get data to the next column. My columns might not be empty and I want them to be overwritten. Also I have some columns which are merged and I want the data to be written in the 3rd next column.

For example I have enter the first value in cell C3 and I want the next one to be in F3 because D3 and E3 were merged and don't exist.

I have tryed using something like :

```
ecolumn = Sheet14.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
```

But with no success. I've tryed `offset(0,3)`, I've tryed `ecolumn+3` but nothing works. It either doesn't accept moving every 3 columns or stops at the second attempt.

Comment: Add some formatting pls.

Comment: Is your input always in column C?  How are you currently inserting data into column C?  Please share the code which adds the data to your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing all your code, it would be something like:

```
'Code that inserts data into cell "C#"
ecolumn = InsertRng.Offset(0, 3)
'InsertRng should be replaced by whatever variable you define the range where you insert the data from your textbox/combobox into cell "C#"
ecolumn.Value = 'Whatever you wanted to put in that offset range
```